# How do I to connect aluminium profiles with 60 and 120 degree angles?

Tags: aluminum, connections

I would like to construct an aluminium profile frame which includes connections with stiff fixed angles at 60 and 120 degrees.

**What options do exist for creating those connections, preferably without having to further process the profiles themselves?**

There are many ways for connecting elements at 0 or 90 and sometimes 45 and 135 degrees, but even with exact cuts at different angles (which I would like to avoid) there do not seem to be many tools for creating other connections available.

Comment: If you're using 8020 extrusions there's a lot of options, like this: http://catalogs.8020.net/80-20-Inc-Catalog-23/338/

Comment: This will depend on the brand which isn't mentioned in your question. Hit the edit link ...